# Firebase project not listed in Google Cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a project in Firebase, and now want to access additional services in GCP. But the Google Cloud console does not list the Firebase project anywhere I can see.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/client/get-firebase) gives instructions for the other direction (importing a GCP project into Firebase). [This post](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f) makes it sound like it should just happen automatically -- but it's not for me.

(I do see all the other projects I've created directly from the google cloud console.)

Answer (score 29):

This happened to me.  I was able to find the new project in the gcp web console as follows:

1. login to the cloud console
2. click on the project pulldown in the top left corner.
   [image]
3. click the "ALL" tab from the "Select a project" modal dialog: you should see your new project in the list.
   [image]

Comment: Happens with me every time I start a new project!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to check the organization. Make sure, you are looking in the same organisation where the firebase project is created.

Comment: Thanks Prabhu -- I'm currently just working out of my personal gmail account in GCP (so no organization). Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Organization is default feature for GCP. You must have choose one organization during firebase project creation. 

On GCP console go to IAM--> manage resource

Check if the project is there. There will be a dropdown on top left corner to switch org. Try that to check if the project is there in any other org.

Comment: That worked. Thank you Prabhu. (My upvote will show up when I get more reputation)